# How to define a skewed normal distribution using mode and two points?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, python, density-function, algorithms

I want to define a Gaussian distribution function and plot it in python using the mode and inflection points parameter values instead of using the mean and standard deviation.

For example, I have `mode=110` and `two points : (40, 160)` for asymmetrical points.

Or `mode=100` and `two points = (50,150)` for symmetrical points.

I tried with this code below, but I don't how I can add the second point to the formula which is returned by the function? Since I have two points, and I don't know how to define a function that depends on two points and mode. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
import numpy as np
matplotlib.pyplot as plt   
def gaussian(x, mode, inf_point):
    return 1/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi)*inf_point)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mode)/inf_point, 2)/2)
x = np.linspace(0,256)
plt.plot(x, gaussian(x, mode, inf_point))
```

Comment: According to [this blog post](https://www.thoughtco.com/inflection-points-of-a-normal-distribution-3126446) a Gaussian normal has two symmetric inflection points, at the mean +/- the sdev. So, your question probably needs to be reformulated.

Comment: @JohanC yes i know but i need to use the mode and inflection points instead the mean and sdev

Comment: A previous comment beat me to it: the second point is symmetric about 0 from the first.  No, I don't know how to use it; my stats class was too long ago.  However, you *should* be able to (a) look up the answer, or (2) get help from the algorithms group.  You might also look for an appropriate stats tag to add.

Comment: @khadoudj what is the difference between symmetric and asymmetric infliction points? Can you link me to an article/video about them? I can't seem to find them...

Comment: @Yatin symmetric points: if the distance between the first point and the mode equals to the distance between the mode and the second point else asymmetric points

Comment: @khadoudj I keep seeing that the points of infliction are located at &mu-&sigma and &mu +&Sigma... then how can they be asymmetrical?

Comment: they can be asymmetrical if they have a skew gaussian distribution

Comment: @khadoudj  So, do you mean skewed normal distribution, or exponentilly modified normal distribution, or lognormal distribution? All three are skewed and are determined by three parameters. But formulas will be different.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg i don't know what is the difference between them and with which one i can use the mode and inflection points, how i can define them using two inflection points and the mode please?

Comment: If the inflection points are not symmetric about the mode, it's not Gaussian. You'll need to clarify what you actually mean.

Comment: Hello, welcome to CrossValidated! I am not sure that I understand the question correctly: the mode is directly equal to mu, and the location of the inflection points relative to the mode gives you sigma. I don't think that you can have two inflections points that are asymmetrical relative to the mode.

Comment: @YuriGinsburg hi, you have an idea how to define one of a skewed distribution using the mode and two inflection  points please?

Comment: @JohanC i want to use the inflection points like thresholds for image segmentation. i have a histogramme which has a curve of the blue. X axis is from 0 to 255, the mode is located at the point 110 and two points (40,160) gives better segementation results so i want to use them to define and plot my new normal distribution

Comment: Since it's extremely difficult--and indirect--to estimate an [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) of a pdf directly and impossible to measure it--it sounds like you intend "inflection point" to have a nonstandard meaning.  Could you provide a definition or explanation within your post?

Answer (score 1):

The following might work for the case explained in the comments.

Given some data, `skewnorm.fit` will try to find parameters for `skewnorm` that fit the data. Such a fit needs good initial parameters.  Some experimenting suggests that when the skewness parameter is initialized with zero, the resulting fit also has a skewness close to zero.  Setting the initial skewness parameter rather high, e.g. 10, seems to generate a fit much closer to the real skewness used for the test data.

The following code first generates some dummy data and draws its histogram and kde. Then a `skewnorm` is fitted to the data, and the pdf of that fit is drawn on the same plot.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import skewnorm

# create some random data from a skewnorm
data = skewnorm.rvs(3, loc=90, scale=50, size=1000).astype(np.int)

# draw a histogram and kde of the given data
ax = sns.distplot(data, kde_kws={'label':'kde of given data'}, label='histogram')

# find parameters to fit a skewnorm to the data
params = skewnorm.fit(data, 10, loc=80, scale=40)

# draw the pdf of the fitted skewnorm
x = np.linspace(0, 255, 500)
ax.plot(x, skewnorm.pdf(x, *params), label='approximated skewnorm')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: @JohancC why you used loc=80 and scale=40 ? and how you find the right loc and scale?

Comment: I just used some test values. You could use half the distance between your special values as guess for the `scale` (sigma). And the point in the middle as initial guess for `loc`. E.g. left 40 and right 160 would give `(160-40)/2=60` as initial `scale` and `(160+40)/2=100` as initial `loc`. It are just educated guesses, which might work (or not) in your particular case.  (In case the kde is sufficient for your needs, you could leave out the `skewnorm`.)

Comment: thank you and what does mean 10 in parameters of  `skewnorm.fit` ?

Comment: It is the initial guess for the `skewness`.  0 means no skew. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) where it is called 'shape' (alpha).